# Deploying with Capistrano: How to set file and folder permissions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, permissions, capistrano

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9, Paperclip and Capistrano gems. When I deploy my application (using Capistrano) on my VPS running Ubuntu 10.04 and I try to submit a Paperclip attachment it will not work. I know that the problem is related to file and folder permissions for the `public` directory (I upload attached files in that directory).

*So, instead of set permissions **manually** every time I deploy my application, I would like to write a Capistrano recipe so to set those permissions in an "automatic" way*. **How can I do that?**

Should I set file and folder permissions in my local machine (Mac OS running Snow Leopard 10.6.7) so that Capistrano will deploy and set those permissions correctly? Or, should I add some code like `system "chmod -R 777 #{RAILS_ROOT}/public"` in the `config/environments/production.rb` file?

Answer (score 3):

You are approaching it wrong.

I'm sure you want to keep your attachments between deploys, don't you?
Then your Paperclip attachments should be under a 'shared' directory, as logs, tmp, pids, etc...

If you respect Paperclip default location: ":rails_root/public/system/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename".
And you don't mangle your SVN or Git with that **public/system** directory.

The solution is as simple as setup once the **:deploy_to/shared/system** directory with your desired permissions. And let both Paperclip and Capistrano handle that system directory seamlessly for you.